# Rails: ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers for multipart/form-data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

In my rails API, I have added an initialiser that will change the keys of the JSON input from snake-case to underscore-separated. Like so:

```
ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers[:json] = -> (raw_post) {
    data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(raw_post)
    data = {:_json => data} unless data.is_a?(Hash)

    data.deep_transform_keys!(&:underscore)
}
```

Now, certain APIs will be passed with the header: `content-type: multipart/form-data` instead of `application/json`

I want to do the same for such APIs. That is add an initialiser that will convert the case of the keys in the parameters.

I tried `ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers[:form_data]` but it dit not work.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I added a parser as suggested in the answer below but it opened a can of worms :(

Comment: Yes, I did. Well, sort of. I could not make it work using `parameters_parsers`. It just doesn't work the way it works for JSON parameters. Let me show you my code by adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you look at the [`DEFAULT_PARSERS`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b7ac0790682e0a56b406127891dfefc15a5eaa64/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb#L7), it uses the `Mime` class, so whatever we end up using will likely need to be recognizable by the `Mime` class. So we can check [Mime::Types](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b7ac0790682e0a56b406127891dfefc15a5eaa64/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_types.rb) to see what's available.

On that page, we see that `content-type: multipart/form-data` is mapped to `:multipart_form`. Indeed, while using

```
ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers[:multipart_form] = -> (raw_post) {
  raise "Parsing Parameters: #{raw_post}"
}
```

and then submitting a form with a file field, I can trigger the error.

Answer (score 1):

Although, according to Simple Lime's answer, `:multipart_form` is the right key for the default parser for requests with `content-type: multipart/form-data`, it does not work like the way it does for JSON.

This is the work around I implemented:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    before_action :transform_params_if_multipart!

    private 
    def transform_params_if_multipart!
        params.deep_transform_keys!(&:underscore) if /^multipart\/form-data*/.match(request.headers['content-type'])
    end
end
```

Comment: This solution works on Rails 5 with a deprecation warning, but Rails 5.1 removes deep_transform_keys! from params, so it's not a good long term solution, and what we probably need is a modification of

`ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers[:multipart_form] = -> (raw_post) {`