# ActionDispatch::ParamsParser replacement after upgrade to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actiondispatch

Migrating an app from Rails 4.2.9 to 5.2.1.

This is latest issue:

```
$ rails console
/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/config/initializers/disable_xml_params.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::ParamsParser (NameError)
    from /Users/meltemi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/meltemi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
    from /Users/meltemi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
```

The offending line of code in an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/disable_xml_params.rb
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::DEFAULT_PARSERS.delete(Mime::XML)
```

[Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/5_0_release_notes.html#action-pack-deprecations) says:

> ActionDispatch::ParamsParser is deprecated and was removed from the middleware stack. To configure the parameter parsers use ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers=. (commit, commit)

So I've tried the following:

```
ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers.delete(Mime::XML)
```

But that begets more errors:

```
$ rails console
/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/config/initializers/disable_xml_params.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Mime::XML (NameError)
    from /Users/meltemi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/meltemi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
    from /Users/meltemi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
```

Is there a better way to call .delete on that object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to grab the existing values from `parameter_parsers`, modify it to suit your needs, then reset the values to your modified values. From the [ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/Parameters/ClassMethods.html#method-i-parameter_parsers-3D):

> `parameter_parsers=(parsers)`
>
> Configure the parameter parser for a given MIME type.
>
> It accepts a hash where the key is the symbol of the MIME type and the value is a proc.

```
original_parsers = ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers
xml_parser = -> (raw_post) { Hash.from_xml(raw_post) || {} }
new_parsers = original_parsers.merge(xml: xml_parser)
ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers = new_parsers
```

In your specific case, you should look at the parsers in `original_parsers` to see if there is anything to delete. On a simple Rails 5 app that I have handy to look at, the only values I have are:

```
=> {
    :json => #<Proc:0x00007fe818fc6fb8@/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0-preview2/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:11 (lambda)>
}
```

Your app's configuration is likely different, but to answer your question about how to delete a value, this simple version should work:

```
ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers = ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers.except(:json)
```

You may find additional useful information [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45096629/3784008).